# Java Error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, jframe, stack-overflow

I was am looking for a solution to this error what is written on the console is    `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)`
Here is my code 
First Class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class testing extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private testing tes = new testing();
private boolean ranOnce = false;

public testing() {
     if (ranOnce = false) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ranOnce = true;
                        tes = new testing();
                        tes.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JLabel lblTest = new JLabel("Test");
    contentPane.add(lblTest, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
}
}
```

Second Class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Test extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test frame = new Test();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnTestButton = new JButton("Test Button");
    btnTestButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            new testing();
        }
    });
    btnTestButton.setBounds(114, 90, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnTestButton);
}
}
```

I am using the eclipse plugin window builder I know the stack-overflow exception is caused by too much memory use and I thought using if(runOnce = false) it world fix it

Comment: For the future: when you have a stack overflow, you have to look for a repeating patern in the call stack. The call stack you're providing cuts off before any such pattern can be detected. Obviously, you cannot provide a complete call stack, but something longer would have been more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the error by removing all the runOnce stuff in the testing class and change the button clicked code to

```
testing s = new testing();
s.setVisible(true);
setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

in the `testing` constructor, you are creating a new instance of `testing` each time you create an instance of `testing`, so you're recursively creating infinite number of `testing` instances.

Your approach to solve this problem is good, but your `ranOnce` boolean is a member variable, as such, there is one per `testing` *instance*, so it is *always* false when you hit the constructor.

You should simply make `ranOnce` static, so that there is only *one* `ranOnce` variable, bound to the *class* and not the *instances*.

EDIT: as stated by Sbodd,  you'll also have to replace

```
private testing tes = new testing();
```

with

```
private testing tes;
```

so that it is not initialized anymore automatically at each constructor call (so that's the second reason why it ran in an infinite recursive way)

Comment: In addition to that, testing's tes member variable is also being initialized with 'new testing()' on each call to testing's constructor - so there are two places where the infinite recursion is happening..

Comment: @Angivare I made run once static and only called new testing once at the start and i still cant get it to work could you please help me

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: As stated Sbodd, you'll also have to replace `private testing tes = new testing()` with `private testing tes`. 
But still, I wonder what you're trying to achieve, why are you creating a `testing` instance insinde `testing` instances?

Comment: @Angivare i am trying to make it so that when you press a button it opens a new window